# Spring Cloud Contract failed to start Stub Runner

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I've made a Consumer side spring-cloud-contract test and it fails on starting the stub server. I see in the logs it is able to download and unpack the stub.jar but then it fails with the following Exception:

```
initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.builder.handlebars.HandlebarsJsonPathHelper incompatible with com.github.jknack.handlebars.Helper
2022-07-11 19:20:59.683  INFO 14704 --- [    Test worker] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-11 19:20:59.694 ERROR 14704 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.builder.handlebars.HandlebarsJsonPathHelper incompatible with com.github.jknack.handlebars.Helper
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

I am using mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.3" with Java 8. It has chosen to use "spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3".

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it was due to a `wiremock` dependency I had in my `build.gradle` file.

Commenting out the below dependency fixed the issue:

```
testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.33.2'
```